# Hide/Encrypt passwords and keys in an Azure Data Factory Project

Tags: c#, azure, security, encryption, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data Factory Visual Studio Project within a GitHub repository, and as part of the configuration I have a few linked services, for example, one for an Asure SQL Database, Azure Blob and one for an Azure Batch, all of these linked services have a connection string or account key.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://datafactories.schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-09-01/Microsoft.DataFactory.LinkedService.json",
  "name": "odsLS",
  "properties": {
    "description": "Connection to ODS database",
    "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
    "typeProperties": {
      "connectionString": "Data Source=tcp:<data_base_server>,1433;Initial Catalog=<data_base_name>;User ID=<user_name>;Password=<password>;Integrated Security=False;Encrypt=True;Connect Timeout=30"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't want to save the sensitive data (passwords, keys etc) to my repository, only change it in the publish to Azure process.

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADFSecurePublish supports store secrets in Azure Key Vault and only need to specify the reference to them in the linked services. Refer to: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/tree/master/Samples/ADFSecurePublish

Answer (score 0):

another option would be to use configuration files which you do not check-in to GitHub